# Error al hacer una transición con css y html

Tags: css, html5

Estoy haciendo un menu vertical el cual tiene un submenu con una transición en la cual salen las opciones de izquierda a derecha, pero al poner la etiqueta `<a>` en los `<li>` no me hace esa transición y no se como sacarlo, a ver si me dais un poco de luz.

```css
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

input[type='radio'] {
    display: none;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

body .swanky .intro {
    float: right;
    color: white;
    width: 370px;
    top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
}

body .swanky .intro h1 {
    text-shadow: 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

body .swanky .intro p {
    line-height: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

body .swanky_wrapper {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 240px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label {
    padding: 25px;
    float: left;
    height: 72px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #131313;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000000;
    transition: text-indent 0.15s, height 0.3s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label img {
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    width: 16px;
    color: black;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label span {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label span a {
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    appearance: none;
    color: black;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label:hover {
    background: #2f7ef5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2A394F;
    text-indent: 4px;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label:hover .bar {
    width: 100%;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label .bar {
    width: 0px;
    transition: width 0.15s;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: #426dad;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label .lil_arrow {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.8s;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    border-top: 2px solid #15a4fa;
    border-right: 2px solid #15a4fa;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
    right: 2px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

body .swanky_wrapper label .lil_arrow:hover {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.8s;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
    right: 2px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content li {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    left: -100%;
    background: #15a4fa;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    text-indent: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px #126CA1 inset;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
    position: relative;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content li:hover {
    background: #0c93e4;
    box-shadow: 3px 0px #126CA1 inset;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear, text-indent 0.3s linear;
    text-indent: 31px;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content li a {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    left: -100%;
    background: #15a4fa;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    text-indent: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px #126CA1 inset;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content li a:hover {
    background: #0c93e4;
    box-shadow: 3px 0px #126CA1 inset;
    transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear, text-indent 0.3s linear;
    text-indent: 31px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content .clear {
    clear: both;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label .swanky_wrapper__content {
    display: block;
    top: 68px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #212e41;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label>.lil_arrow {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
    transition: transform 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    border-top: 2px solid white;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label {
    height: 200px;
    background: #426dad;
    text-indent: 4px;
    transition-property: height;
    transition-duration: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    color: white;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label .bar {
    width: 0;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label:nth-of-type(4) {
    animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

@keyframes in {
    from {
        left: -100%;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="menuVertical">
      <div class="swanky">
      
      <div class="swanky_wrapper">
      <header>
            <img src="img/logo-azul.png" />
        <br>
        <br>
      </header>
        <label for="Dashboard">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/50/000000/dog-house.png"/>
          <span><a href="principal.php">Inicio</a></span>
          
        </label>
        <input id="Sales" name="radio" type="radio"></input>
        <label for="Sales">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/warning-shield.png"/>
          <span>Incidencia</span>
          <div class="lil_arrow"></div>
          <div class="bar"></div>
          <div class="swanky_wrapper__content">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Crear Incidencia</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Buscar Incidencia</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </label>
        <label for="Messages">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/000000/server.png"/>
          <span>Servidores</span>
        </label>
        
        <label for="Users">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/chat.png"/>
          <span>Chat</span>
        
        </label>
      </div>
      <!--/////////// End Dropdown ////////////
      -->
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Bueno realmente lo que he notado es lo siguiente:*

***En el css oibservo estas 2 clases***

```css
body .swanky_wrapper__content li {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100%;
  background: #15a4fa;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #126CA1 inset;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content li a {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  left: -100%;
  background: #15a4fa;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #126CA1 inset;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

*Si quieres que se visualice los < li > elimina de estas 2 clases el **left: -100%** y cambia el valor de la opacidad, si lo dejas en 0 no se va a visualizar nada. como ejemplo te cambio el de la primer clase con opacidad en 1 y el segundo en 0,6, quedando de la siguiente manera:*

```css
body .swanky_wrapper__content li {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  /* left: -100%; */
  background: #15a4fa;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #126CA1 inset;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content li a {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.6;
  /* left: -100%; */
  background: #15a4fa;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #126CA1 inset;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

*Como puedes ver he comentado el left de ambas clases, adjunto tu código con estos dos ajustes para que observes:*

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

body .swanky .intro {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  width: 370px;
  top: 50px;
  position: fixed;
}

body .swanky .intro h1 {
  text-shadow: 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

body .swanky .intro p {
  line-height: 20px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}

body .swanky_wrapper {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 240px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label {
  padding: 25px;
  float: left;
  height: 72px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #131313;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000000;
  transition: text-indent 0.15s, height 0.3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label img {
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  width: 16px;
  color: black;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label span {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label span a {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  appearance: none;
  color: black;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label:hover {
  background: #2f7ef5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2A394F;
  text-indent: 4px;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label:hover .bar {
  width: 100%;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label .bar {
  width: 0px;
  transition: width 0.15s;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: #426dad;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

body .swanky_wrapper label .lil_arrow {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  border-top: 2px solid #15a4fa;
  border-right: 2px solid #15a4fa;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  right: 2px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

body .swanky_wrapper label .lil_arrow:hover {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  right: 2px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content li {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  /* left: -100%; */
  background: #15a4fa;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #126CA1 inset;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content li:hover {
  background: #0c93e4;
  box-shadow: 3px 0px #126CA1 inset;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear, text-indent 0.3s linear;
  text-indent: 31px;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content li a {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  /* left: -100%; */
  background: #15a4fa;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-indent: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px #126CA1 inset;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s, text-indent 0.3s;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content li a:hover {
  background: #0c93e4;
  box-shadow: 3px 0px #126CA1 inset;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s linear, text-indent 0.3s linear;
  text-indent: 31px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

body .swanky_wrapper__content .clear {
  clear: both;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label .swanky_wrapper__content {
  display: block;
  top: 68px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #212e41;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label>.lil_arrow {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label {
  height: 200px;
  background: #426dad;
  text-indent: 4px;
  transition-property: height;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  color: white;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label .bar {
  width: 0;
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.575s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.7s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.825s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

input[type='radio']:checked+label:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  -moz-animation: in 0.15s 0.95s forwards;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}

@keyframes in {
  from {
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="menuVertical">
  <div class="swanky">

    <div class="swanky_wrapper">
      <header>
        <img src="img/logo-azul.png" />
        <br>
        <br>
      </header>
      <label for="Dashboard">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/50/000000/dog-house.png" />
                    <span><a href="principal.php">Inicio</a></span>

                </label>
      <input id="Sales" name="radio" type="radio"></input>
      <label for="Sales">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/warning-shield.png" />
                    <span>Incidencia</span>
                    <div class="lil_arrow"></div>
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                    <div class="swanky_wrapper__content">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Crear Incidencia</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Buscar Incidencia</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </label>
      <label for="Messages">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/24/000000/server.png" />
                    <span>Servidores</span>
                </label>

      <label for="Users">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/chat.png" />
                    <span>Chat</span>

                </label>
    </div>
    <!--/////////// End Dropdown ////////////
        -->
  </div>
</div>
```

*Espero te sirva y ya queda para que continues ajustandolo como desees.*

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge, me ha servido!

Comment: @Flowcou con gusto, no olvides aceptar la respuesta si esta te ha servido, buen día